# Datatables loop only rows by indexes

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've a datatables where i've to some iteration/math calc., but only some row i need to read, by an index array passed by another function.

For example if i've an array of indexes like: `arr = [0,1,3,5];` i need to loop inside the table limited for rows: 0,1,3,5 only.

This is my fiddle that loops ALL rows:

http://jsfiddle.net/bbLjzspf/5398/

I don't know how to limit the loop.

Important: I know i can loop all rows and check if the rowIdx is in array `arr` to do my calc., but for some problems/variables I omitted in this example, I can't used this method. **I need to limit loop only!**

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution myself:

```
var arr = [0,1,3,5];

myTable.rows(arr, { order: 'applied' }).every(function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {

    alert(rowIdx);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbLjzspf/5406/